# React + redux project not launching with instructions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, yarnpkg

This is my first React + Redux project, it works when I run it in my PC but when people follow my github instructions to run the project on their computers they get an error. "command not found: yarn"

Can anyone help me with this issue please? I wonder if my instructions are wrong in the first place
https://github.com/itsandromeda/Shoes-Store

*If anyone gets to launch it succesfully without any errors please let me know.*

Instructions:

## Install dependencies

```
npm install
```

## Install json server

```
npm install -g json-server
```

## Run json server

```
json-server --watch db.json --port 3001
```

## Launch project

```
yarn start
```

Comment: please add the error that they get, using my ubuntu  i get ```json-server: command not found```, but i make it working. it could be not working on linux.

Comment: Maybe they don't have node and npm installed

Comment: They get the error "command not found: yarn"

Comment: @AnniaJ.Flores have them run `npm start`

Comment: I'll try that Derek, I'll see if it works, thank you!

Comment: Then they don't have `yarn` installed.

Comment: `yarn` needs to be installed on the user's machine, it's prerequisite. Alternatively `npm start` can be used but for that too `npm` needs to be installed (which will be there as first 2 steps also requires it, so it won't be a problem)

Comment: Your repo. also works for me, tested locally and [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/worrq6ro8k). At codesandbox I've slightly modified your code to change loading of json.

Answer (score 0):

It all worked for me. I'm using node `v8.9.4` and npm `5.6.0`